# HttpWebResponse stripping newline characters

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse, strip

I'm using the following code to read the response:

```
using (Stream MyResponseStream = hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
{
        byte[] MyBuffer = new byte[4096];
        int BytesRead;

        while (0 < (BytesRead = MyResponseStream.Read(MyBuffer, 0, MyBuffer.Length)))
        {  
            ByteArrayToFile("request.txt", MyBuffer, BytesRead);
        }
}
```

This is the function to write to a file:

```
public void ByteArrayToFile(string _FileName, byte[] _ByteArray, int BytesRead)
{
        System.IO.FileStream _FileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(_FileName, System.IO.FileMode.Append, System.IO.FileAccess.Write);
        _FileStream.Write(_ByteArray, 0, BytesRead);
        _FileStream.Close();
}
```

If I use webclient, I get new lines everything is parsed correctly. When I use HttpWebResponse new line characters get stripped (not all, but 80%). Any hints why this is happening? Thanks!

Comment: That is terribly inefficient.  Try holding the file open until you have finished writing to it, instead of opening/closing it for each write operation.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still facing the newline problem though.. Any tips how to deal with it?

Comment: Looks like you are just writing a text file... you could try a system.io.streamreader instead of chunking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the following code to write the entire response to a file:

```
using (StreamReader MyResponseStream = new StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    using (StreamWriter _FileStream = new StreamWriter("request.txt", true))
    {
        _FileStream.Write(MyResponseStream.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```